# Handling event when click on a button in a ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I have an idea to create an android app with have ability to load Video from a server.

At first, I'd like to display all video information (such as Title, singer, etc.) in an ExpandableListView, having a Play button (an imageButton) in every group. When user click on the group, the child will be expanded includes extra information (such as Description). And when user click on the Play button, video will be load from server to play on a VideoView, which located on above of the ExpandableListView

Here is my layouts

video_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_selected"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Selected: "/>
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expList_movie_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

For demo purpose, I replaced a textview called tv_selected instead of a VideoView

video_list_group.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cho nguoi noi ay"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_publishDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="01/02/2013"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_singer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Uyen Linh"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_publishDate"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn_Play"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_length"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3:30"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgBtn_Play"/>


</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

video_list_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ln_child_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dip" >
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TableRow >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Composer:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_composer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Huy Tuan"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Lyric:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_lyric"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Ha Quang Minh"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Description:"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="MỸ NHÂN KẾ - Bộ phim hành động 3D của mỹ nhân Việt. Một tác phẩm của Nguyễn Quang Dũng, các diễn viên Tăng Thanh Hà, Thanh Hằng, Thái Hòa Lê, Diễm My 9x, Ngọc Quyên, Anh Khoa..."/>   

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have finished display the information in groups and children perfectly.

So, I wanna display the title of video when user click on the Play button to the tv_selected.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the text of the tv_selected textView, just write `tv_selected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_selected); tv_selected.setText("TITLE");`

Comment: well, I want to setOnClickLister for the imgBtn_Play in order to setText for the tv_selected. The problem is imgBtn_play and tv_selected belongs to 2 different layouts.